# Lead Assignment email alert notification no longer working

Tags: workflow, assignment-rules, sales

Web-to-lead lead assignment notification email alerts have suddenly stopped sending to outlook inbox. I should receive all workflow email alerts as the person cc'd with the lead owner as the main person in the email.

**What I have tried**

1. checked SF email log and they are showing as sent however I am not seeing them in my inbox.
2. checked Deliverability settings and they are correct to show 'all emails'
3. sent test from email template and is working fine
4. did IP address checks and have received all that were sent

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390823&type=1), check if 'Stop Automated Field Updates from Suppressing Email Notifications' is enabled in your org and this may resolve the issue if everything else is setup correctly.

Also, review more details on above release update [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_pbuilder_cruc_process_emails.htm&type=5&release=228), along with [Ensure you can receive email from the Salesforce application](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388992&type=1).

Comment: thank you for your help. Managed to figure it out - was an issue with company email software blocking them